# How to skip default encoding done by web.py render or what is the best way to decode it as JSON variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, json, web.py

I have a python dictionary being passed to javascript in web.py framework. The double quotes in the dict are replaced by special characters and I am unable to get back to original format. Is there any way to avoid the encoding OR what is the ideal way to decode it? I have tried JSON.dumps on the dict but that again does a different encoding and I could not decode it using JSON.parse or eval.

Same dictionary format declared inline the javascript perfectly works as a JSON variable.

I am new to JSON and javascript and prefer not to write a new decoding function of my own.

My dict variable:

```
{'slca': [{'hssInit': 14}, {'hssFail': 2}], 'slcb': [{'hssInit': 15}, {'hssFail': 3}], 'phx': [{'hssInit': 12}, {'hssFail': 1}]}
```

Encoded var:

```
 var myData = "{&#39;slca&#39;: [{&#39;hssInit&#39;: 14}, {&#39;hssFail&#39;: 2}], &#39;slcb&#39;: [{&#39;hssInit&#39;: 15}, {&#39;hssFail&#39;: 3}], &#39;phx&#39;: [{&#39;hssInit&#39;: 12}, {&#39;hssFail&#39;: 1}]}";
```

Oops- the special characters are automatically converted to string when I paste it here.
Looks like I am missing something very basic. But the javascript throws syntax error for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would really need to see some code to find out how web.py is returning your dictionary, however the problem is most likely that your dictionary is being returned as a string. That's why you're getting the `&#39;` character code (an apostrophe, not a double quote). So you aren't actually getting JSON, you are getting str(yourdict). It's close, but not right.

If your code looks something like:

```
def GET(self):
    return {'prop1': 'val', 'prop2': 4}
```

Try using the json module to translate your dictionary

```
import json

# ...

def GET(self):
    data = {'prop1': 'val', 'prop2': 4}
    return json.dumps(data)
```